# How do I extract information from a JSON object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, frontend

I want to get city from the given api and display it. The output on console is undefined.This is what I have so far:

```
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(data1){

    city = data1.city;
     $("#city").html(city);

  });
    console.log(city);
```

How can I do this successfully?

Comment: In your case, you have an Asynchronous call, so when console.log is called city is undefined. you should move console.log within the success callback

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(data1) {
  city = data1.city;
  $("#city").html(city);
  console.log(city);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="city"></div>
```